# ggplot2 won't install in rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, package, installation

I have 3 students in a class of 20 who can't get ggplot2 to install on their computers (all older Macs running 10.8 to 10.10) via Rstudio. Their error messages are below. It seems like they are running the right code, and I don't understand why it won't work on their computers. Any suggestions of what to try next would be much appreciated.

**Student 1**

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) -- "Another Canoe"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)


> install.packages("ggplot2")
also installing the dependencies ‘digest’, ‘scales’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
        binary source needs_compilation
digest  0.6.13 0.6.16              TRUE
scales   0.5.0  1.0.0              TRUE
ggplot2  2.2.1  3.0.0             FALSE

Do you want to install from sources the packages which need compilation?
y/n: y
installing the source packages ‘digest’, ‘scales’, ‘ggplot2’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/digest_0.6.16.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 123969 bytes (121 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 121 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/scales_1.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 299262 bytes (292 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 292 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2847050 bytes (2.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.7 MB

* installing *source* package ‘digest’ ...
** package ‘digest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c aes.c -o aes.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c crc32.c -o crc32.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c digest.c -o digest.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c init.c -o init.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c md5.c -o md5.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c pmurhash.c -o pmurhash.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c raes.c -o raes.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c sha1.c -o sha1.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c sha2.c -o sha2.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c sha256.c -o sha256.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c xxhash.c -o xxhash.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o digest.so aes.o crc32.o digest.o init.o md5.o pmurhash.o raes.o sha1.o sha2.o sha256.o xxhash.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/digest/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (digest)
* installing *source* package ‘scales’ ...
** package ‘scales’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c colors.cpp -o colors.o
clang++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o scales.so RcppExports.o colors.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/scales/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (scales)
* installing *source* package ‘ggplot2’ ...
** package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (ggplot2)

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/16/0m9qg4c57_3ff2sjqj4m8gqr0000gn/T/RtmpenBrUz/downloaded_packages’
```

**Students 2**

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) -- "Another Canoe"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)


> install.packages("ggplot2")

  There is a binary version available but the source version
  is later:
        binary source needs_compilation
ggplot2  2.2.1  3.0.0             FALSE

installing the source package ‘ggplot2’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2847050 bytes (2.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.7 MB

* installing *source* package ‘ggplot2’ ...
** package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error : object ‘enexprs’ is not exported by 'namespace:rlang'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘ggplot2’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/ggplot2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/tr/f5zb5kf16pxdx4b8qtkw3cc00000gn/T/RtmpiNIZN2/downloaded_packages’
```

**Student 3**

```
> install.packages("ggplot2")

Warning in install.packages :
  dependencies ‘rgeos’, ‘sf’ are not available
also installing the dependencies ‘fansi’, ‘utf8’, ‘curl’, ‘openssl’, ‘bindr’, ‘pillar’, ‘checkmate’, ‘rstudioapi’, ‘zoo’, ‘memoise’, ‘whisker’, ‘git2r’, ‘fontBitstreamVera’, ‘fontLiberation’, ‘httpuv’, ‘xtable’, ‘sourcetools’, ‘later’, ‘promises’, ‘stringi’, ‘backports’, ‘xfun’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘rex’, ‘httr’, ‘bindrcpp’, ‘glue’, ‘pkgconfig’, ‘Rcpp’, ‘tibble’, ‘tidyselect’, ‘BH’, ‘plogr’, ‘survival’, ‘Formula’, ‘latticeExtra’, ‘acepack’, ‘gridExtra’, ‘data.table’, ‘htmlTable’, ‘viridis’, ‘htmltools’, ‘base64enc’, ‘sp’, ‘mvtnorm’, ‘TH.data’, ‘sandwich’, ‘praise’, ‘devtools’, ‘fontquiver’, ‘gdtools’, ‘htmlwidgets’, ‘purrr’, ‘shiny’, ‘xml2’, ‘SparseM’, ‘MatrixModels’, ‘evaluate’, ‘highr’, ‘markdown’, ‘stringr’, ‘yaml’, ‘rprojroot’, ‘mime’, ‘tinytex’, ‘rlang’, ‘scales’, ‘covr’, ‘dplyr’, ‘ggplot2movies’, ‘hexbin’, ‘Hmisc’, ‘mapproj’, ‘maps’, ‘maptools’, ‘multcomp’, ‘testthat’, ‘vdiffr’, ‘quantreg’, ‘knitr’, ‘rmarkdown’, ‘svglite’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions
  are later:
              binary   source needs_compilation
curl             1.2      3.2              TRUE
openssl        0.9.2    1.0.2              TRUE
checkmate      1.8.1    1.8.5              TRUE
rstudioapi       0.6      0.7             FALSE
zoo           1.7-13    1.8-3              TRUE
memoise        1.0.0    1.1.0             FALSE
git2r         0.15.0   0.23.0              TRUE
httpuv         1.3.3    1.4.5              TRUE
xtable         1.8-2    1.8-3             FALSE
stringi        1.1.1    1.2.4             FALSE
backports      1.0.3    1.1.2             FALSE
jsonlite         1.0      1.5              TRUE
rex            1.1.1    1.1.2             FALSE
httr           1.2.1    1.3.1             FALSE
pkgconfig      2.0.0    2.0.2             FALSE
Rcpp          0.12.6  0.12.18              TRUE
tibble           1.1    1.4.2              TRUE
BH          1.60.0-2 1.66.0-1             FALSE
survival      2.39-5   2.42-6              TRUE
Formula        1.2-1    1.2-3             FALSE
acepack      1.3-3.3    1.4.1              TRUE
gridExtra      2.2.1      2.3             FALSE
data.table     1.9.6   1.11.4              TRUE
htmlTable        1.6     1.12             FALSE
viridis        0.3.4    0.5.1             FALSE
htmltools      0.3.5    0.3.6              TRUE
sp             1.2-3    1.3-1              TRUE
mvtnorm        1.0-5    1.0-8              TRUE
TH.data        1.0-7    1.0-9             FALSE
sandwich       2.3-4    2.5-0             FALSE
devtools      1.12.0   1.13.6              TRUE
htmlwidgets      0.7      1.2             FALSE
purrr          0.2.2    0.2.5              TRUE
shiny         0.13.2    1.1.0             FALSE
xml2           1.0.0    1.2.0              TRUE
SparseM          1.7     1.77              TRUE
evaluate         0.9     0.11             FALSE
highr            0.6      0.7             FALSE
markdown       0.7.7      0.8              TRUE
stringr        1.0.0    1.3.1             FALSE
yaml          2.1.13    2.2.0              TRUE
rprojroot      1.0-2    1.3-2             FALSE
scales         0.4.0    1.0.0              TRUE
covr           2.2.1    3.1.0              TRUE
dplyr          0.5.0    0.7.6              TRUE
hexbin        1.27.1   1.27.2              TRUE
Hmisc         3.17-4    4.1-1              TRUE
mapproj        1.2-4    1.2.6              TRUE
maps           3.1.1    3.3.0              TRUE
maptools      0.8-39    0.9-3              TRUE
multcomp       1.4-6    1.4-8             FALSE
testthat       1.0.2    2.0.0              TRUE
quantreg        5.26     5.36              TRUE
knitr           1.14     1.20             FALSE
rmarkdown        1.0     1.10             FALSE
ggplot2        2.1.0    3.0.0             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
Packages which are only available in source form, and may need
  compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘fansi’ ‘utf8’ ‘sourcetools’
  ‘later’ ‘promises’ ‘bindrcpp’ ‘glue’ ‘tidyselect’ ‘gdtools’
  ‘rlang’ ‘vdiffr’ ‘svglite’
  These will not be installed

The downloaded binary packages are in
/var/folders/vr/mhm7jvp50x1f7t_1ppv6d9rw0000gn/T//Rtmp9juQRH/downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘bindr’, ‘pillar’, ‘rstudioapi’, ‘memoise’, ‘fontBitstreamVera’, ‘fontLiberation’, ‘xtable’, ‘stringi’, ‘backports’, ‘xfun’, ‘rex’, ‘httr’, ‘pkgconfig’, ‘BH’, ‘plogr’, ‘Formula’, ‘gridExtra’, ‘htmlTable’, ‘viridis’, ‘TH.data’, ‘sandwich’, ‘fontquiver’, ‘htmlwidgets’, ‘shiny’, ‘evaluate’, ‘highr’, ‘stringr’, ‘rprojroot’, ‘tinytex’, ‘multcomp’, ‘knitr’, ‘rmarkdown’, ‘ggplot2’

* installing *source* package ‘bindr’ ...
** package ‘bindr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** preparing package for lazy loading
* DONE (bindr)
ERROR: dependencies ‘fansi’, ‘rlang’, ‘utf8’ are not available for package ‘pillar’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/pillar’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘rstudioapi’ ...
** package ‘rstudioapi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** preparing package for lazy loading
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (rstudioapi)
* installing *source* package ‘memoise’ ...
** package ‘memoise’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
* DONE (memoise)
* installing *source* package ‘fontBitstreamVera’ ...
** package ‘fontBitstreamVera’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** inst
** help
No man pages found in package  ‘fontBitstreamVera’ 
* DONE (fontBitstreamVera)
* installing *source* package ‘fontLiberation’ ...
** package ‘fontLiberation’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
No man pages found in package  ‘fontLiberation’ 
* DONE (fontLiberation)
* installing *source* package ‘xtable’ ...
** package ‘xtable’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (xtable)
* installing *source* package ‘stringi’ ...
** package ‘stringi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for R_HOME... /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
checking for R... /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R
checking for endianness... little
checking for R >= 3.1.0 for C++11 use... yes
checking for R < 3.4.0 for CXX1X flag use... yes
checking for cat... /bin/cat
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 150: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 151: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 152: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 153: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 269: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 150: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 151: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 152: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 153: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 269: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 150: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 151: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 152: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 153: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 269: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 150: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 151: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 152: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 153: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 269: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 150: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 151: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 152: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 153: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 269: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 150: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 151: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 152: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 153: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 269: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 150: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 151: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 152: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 153: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 269: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 150: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 151: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 152: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 153: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 269: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 150: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 151: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 152: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 153: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 269: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 150: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 151: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 152: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 153: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 269: make: command not found
checking for local ICUDT_DIR... icu61/data
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/vr/mhm7jvp50x1f7t_1ppv6d9rw0000gn/T/RtmpD45efN/R.INSTALL22546d2eca12/stringi':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘stringi’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/stringi’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘backports’ ...
** package ‘backports’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
sh: make: command not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘backports’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/backports’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘backports’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘xfun’ ...
** package ‘xfun’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
* DONE (xfun)
* installing *source* package ‘rex’ ...
** package ‘rex’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (rex)
* installing *source* package ‘httr’ ...
** package ‘httr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (httr)
* installing *source* package ‘pkgconfig’ ...
** package ‘pkgconfig’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (pkgconfig)
* installing *source* package ‘BH’ ...
** package ‘BH’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (BH)
* installing *source* package ‘plogr’ ...
** package ‘plogr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (plogr)
* installing *source* package ‘Formula’ ...
** package ‘Formula’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (Formula)
* installing *source* package ‘gridExtra’ ...
** package ‘gridExtra’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (gridExtra)
* installing *source* package ‘TH.data’ ...
** package ‘TH.data’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** demo
** inst
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Warning: package ‘survival’ was built under R version 3.2.5
* DONE (TH.data)
* installing *source* package ‘sandwich’ ...
** package ‘sandwich’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (sandwich)
* installing *source* package ‘htmlwidgets’ ...
** package ‘htmlwidgets’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Failed with error:  ‘there is no package called ‘shiny’’
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (htmlwidgets)
* installing *source* package ‘highr’ ...
** package ‘highr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (highr)
ERROR: dependency ‘rlang’ is not available for package ‘ggplot2’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/ggplot2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘ggplot2’ is not available for package ‘viridis’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/viridis’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘viridis’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘fontquiver’ ...
** package ‘fontquiver’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (fontquiver)
ERROR: dependencies ‘sourcetools’, ‘later’, ‘promises’, ‘rlang’ are not available for package ‘shiny’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/shiny’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘glue’, ‘stringi’ are not available for package ‘stringr’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/stringr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘backports’ is not available for package ‘rprojroot’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rprojroot’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rprojroot’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘tinytex’ ...
** package ‘tinytex’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (tinytex)
* installing *source* package ‘multcomp’ ...
** package ‘multcomp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning: package ‘mvtnorm’ was built under R version 3.2.3
Warning: package ‘survival’ was built under R version 3.2.5
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Warning: package ‘mvtnorm’ was built under R version 3.2.3
Warning: package ‘survival’ was built under R version 3.2.5
* DONE (multcomp)
ERROR: dependency ‘stringr’ is not available for package ‘evaluate’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/evaluate’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘evaluate’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘evaluate’, ‘stringr’ are not available for package ‘knitr’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/knitr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘knitr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘stringr’, ‘knitr’ are not available for package ‘htmlTable’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/htmlTable’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘htmlTable’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘knitr’, ‘evaluate’, ‘rprojroot’, ‘stringr’ are not available for package ‘rmarkdown’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rmarkdown’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rmarkdown’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/vr/mhm7jvp50x1f7t_1ppv6d9rw0000gn/T/Rtmp9juQRH/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Student 1: the output looks normal, why do you think it isn't installed? Student 2: suggest you manually re-install/update `rlang` first, must be missing something in depdendencies. Student 3: same for `rlang` and some other packages, attempt before retrying `ggplot2`. Also, `make: command not found` seems rather clear to me, that likely needs to be its own question since it is unrelated to dependency problems (plaguing student 2); or perhaps it's already been answered, I'm not proficient with macs.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to try is to have them first update to the latest version of R. The first two are running 3.3.3, and the third is running some version of 3.2. The latest version is 3.5.1.

For Student 2, the problem is that `rlang` needs to be updated first; this was a dependency that was missed, but I believe now fixed, so updating R (so you can use the latest ggplot version) should help. For details see https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2732.

For Student 3, `rgeos` and `sf`, as mentioned in the first error message, require at least R 3.3.0.